# VS2017 - Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path

Tags: xamarin, uwp, portable-class-library, visual-studio-2017, pdb-files

I have a Xamarin project (UWP and iOS) building and running well in VS2015.
The project contains some Universal Windows and iOS projects, and many PCL used by both platforms (for the view models, the services and the database access).

One by one, the PCLs are building correctly.

But when I try to build the main Universal Windows project I get this error :

```
Error   APPX1101
Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'One.Of.My.Project.pdb'
Source files: 'My.UniversalWindows.Project.scproj'
```

When I go in the file explorer I can find the pdb file in both \bin and \obj directory.

In VS2015, everything is building / running well. I have this build error only on VS2017.

The Target and Min version of my UWP projects are Build 14393 (Anniversary Edition) and my NuGet packages are updated (specially Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform in v5.3.1)

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue with your description. Have you tried to create new PCL  blank app by using VS2017?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clean / Rebuild was not enough (I also tried to remove all the bin/ and obj/ folders)...

I have deleteD my local repo and make a new git clone : Solved

Comment: Just deleted the bin and obj folders from the test project and its dependent app project then rebuilt both. The error went away. Have seen errors like this disappear with a Visual Studio restart as well.

Comment: For me just restarting Visual Studio fixed the error.

Comment: I had to delete the local repo and clone a new one as well. VS restart worked once. then after few days error appeared again. deleting bin and obj folders didn't work